# deploy-manifest action has failed with the error mentioned in the summary

Tags: github, github-actions, digital-ocean, continuous-deployment, github-secret

> Error: .github/workflows/deploy-manifest.yml (Line: 16, Col: 11):
> Unexpected value 'token:***'
>
> Error: The template is not valid.
> .github/workflows/deploy-manifest.yml (Line: 16, Col: 11): Unexpected
> value 'token:***'

### deploy-manifests.yml

```
name: deploy-manifests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    paths:
      - 'infra/**'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install doctl
        uses: digitalocean/action-doctl@v2
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.DIGITALOCEAN_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      - name: Save DigitalOcean kubeconfig
        run: doctl kubernetes cluster kubeconfig save ticketing
      - run: kubectl apply -f infra/k8s && kubectl apply -f infra/k8s-prod
```

I have added all the secrets with the same name as mentioned in yml under the repository level Github.
[github secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zufxb.png)
[github workflows/actions error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l7tq.png)

Please help out in sorting this issue.